# How to custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, captcha

I used to using Spring-MVC, spring security. The checking of account password is automatic.

I have captcha and I want to checking-handle captcha at the same time as checking account and password.

Can I custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to do it. And how it config in my Security config? Is there a better solution?

[image]

Comment: Yes you can, try adding a filter before or after in the security builder

Comment: can you be more specific I am doing this and am having problems